# Django Updating a Value before a Save

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to update a counter in a model to save database queries. So I have an article model with a picture_count field. Pictures are m2m with the article.

When every I add or remove a picture from the article (using Django Admin) I want to update the article picture_count. But it seems that I'm going about it wrong.

I thought I could simply override the save method of my article model. But this doesn't work as the

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.picCount = self.pictures.count()
    super(Articles, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

The problem is that the m2m haven't been updated yet. I have tried calling it after (then calling save again) but the object is outdated. Should I refresh the object and save it again or is there a better place to update this count?

Comment: Where are you doing this?  In a custom form?  Can you attach an attribute to the model that only returns an integer which is the count of related pic records?

Comment: Note, this isn't really a good idea generally. It's much better to calculate that count when you need it, eg via aggregation. Databases are really good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're handling m2m relations, you want to override the [`save_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) method.

**Admin.py**

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    self.picCount = self.pictures.count()
    super(Articles, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

Note that if you're using python 3.x you don't have to pass anything to `super` call.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that super was simplified like that. Good to know.